# previous entry in textbox gets deleted in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have crated a login and registration form.
the text in first two text boxes disappears when i type the text in the third text box.

this is to check that password entered in text-box 2 and 3 is the same or not. if its same then write it in a file else display the message box.

```
private void TextBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if (textBox2.Text == textBox3.Text)
        {
                FileStream register = new FileStream("store.txt", 
                FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
                StreamWriter open = new StreamWriter(register);
                textBox1.Text = Console.ReadLine(); 
                textBox2.Text = Console.ReadLine();
                open.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
                open.WriteLine(textBox2.Text);
                open.Close();
                register.Close();
        }
        else
                MessageBox.Show("something went wrong");
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the _Console.ReadLine()_ BEFORE writing the content of the two textbox to a file?

Comment: i mean, wont it read the contents of the textbox into the file?

Comment: @TazmeenAnoosha What do you imagine Console.ReadLine() does, and why did you think your imagination was a more reliable reference [than the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netframework-4.8)? You can't write code by making up stories about what methods might do. You have to find out what they really do.

Comment: `Console.Readline()` definitely doesn't do what you think it does, and also it's super weird that you're even using `Console.ReadLine` in a WinForms application.

Comment: it seems i was wrong about this method, thank you for pointing it out, ill do more search on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to start by learning basic programming concepts.

In one of your comments on the original post you say *"i mean, wont it read the contents of the textbox into the file?".*

However the two lines of code you refer to are these:

```
textBox1.Text = Console.ReadLine(); 
textBox2.Text = Console.ReadLine();
```

In any kind of programming, the way an *assignment* work is that whatever is on the right hand side of the `=` sign is put into whatever is on the left hand side of it. So, following means the value `5` is put into the variable `abc`:

```
int abc = 5;
```

And following the same idea, in your code:

```
textBox1.Text = Console.ReadLine();
```

This means whatever the function `ReadLine()` returns will be put into `textBox1.Text`. In this case, `Console.ReadLine()` returns an empty string, which is put into the text box text, which is why the text 'disappears' as you claim.

So to answer your question, you should have this but delete the above two `Console.ReadLine()` statements.

```
open.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
open.WriteLine(textBox2.Text);
```

But really, before that, you should probably study basic programming concepts and get those down first.

Comment: thank you so much for this, I've just began C# and couldn't get my head around the winforms.

Answer (score 0):

Using Console.Readline() you overwrite those textboxes with empty text.

```
private void TextBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text == textBox3.Text)
        {
            FileStream register = new FileStream("store.txt",
            FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter open = new StreamWriter(register);
            open.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
            open.WriteLine(textBox2.Text);
            open.Close();
            register.Close();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("something went wrong");
    }
```